# TypeORM: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when creating migration

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeorm

I came across a problem when setting up TypeORM within my NextJS typescript project whereby i was getting the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when trying to create migration from my entities.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to update my package.json and also create a tsconfig for ts-node.

```
"typeorm:local": "yarn local ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
"local": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env.local TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig.ts-node.json TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true ts-node -r dotenv/config"
"g:migration": "yarn typeorm:local migration:generate -n",
"g:entity": "yarn typeorm:local entity:create -n",
```

The tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": { "module": "commonjs" }
}
```

If you are using module: commonjs then you wont need to make this change.